# Copied data column is not partitioned in target table in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have created  a table in hive from existing partitioned table using the command

```
create table new_table As select * from old_table;
```

Record counts are matching in both the table but when I give DESC table I could see the column is not partitioned in New table.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly specify `partition` columns when creating the table.

```
create table new_table partitioned by (col1 datatype,col2 datatype,...) as  
select * from old_table;
```

Comment: Can you use * are the projection? Don't the partition columns always need to be last?